# Creating new Ruby on Rails Project dosn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I together I have installed ruby and the actual rails version on my passenger modul for apache2

so now I want to create my first app with this command:

```
rails new ./testrails -d mysql
```

But I got this error:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.18    for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-   0.3.18/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.18), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.18'` succeeds before bundling.
     run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.8.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:369:in   `resolve': Could not find gem 'turbolinks (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on    this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.8.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:167:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.8.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:129:in `resolve'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.8.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:193:in `resolve'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.8.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.8.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.8.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.8.3/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.8.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.8.3/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `setup'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.8.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
```

I have an running mysql server on the machine...

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: i'm running with debian 7

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

gem install mysql2
```

Comment: should i do this also when there is a stable mysql server running?

Comment: I think so, but I think `libmysqlclient-dev` is used only for header files

Comment: okay it looks like its working ... I've only done this sudo apt-get install libmysqld-dev libmysqlclient-dev and then I did rails server. now there is a port mentioned i should use. localhost:3000